# How to dynamically generate a component withing a component/directive?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a wrapper for different angularjs components. That wrapper have some have html code and some common functions.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>{{header}}</h1>
    <!--place for a component that has been passed through bindings-->
    </div>
```

So ideally, I want to pass a name of a child component to this one and have it render it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure you can achieve that by passing names of components, but you could definitely use the [AngularJS transclude directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude)

For example:

JS

```
var app = angular.module('AppModule', []);

app.directive('wrapperDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="wrapper">' +
            '<h1>Example transclude</h1>' +
            '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</div>',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {}
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app='AppModule'>
    <wrapper-dir>
        <h2>Content to transclude</h2>
        <div>Other stuff, including other directives</div>
    </wrapper-dir>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/j6xudc5k/)